# Windows 8.1 - set up idle timeout with password

Tags: windows-8.1

how can I set the timeout for idle password protected, leaving unchanged the status of the computer (continuing downloads, activities, etc.)?

Comment: This is handled by a group policy and/or turning on say a screen saver with the cnofiguration to lock the computer.  If this isn't what you need describe what your trying to achieve better.

Comment: With the standard configuration my OS stop his activity. I just wont a password after idle timeout compromising activities and connection

Comment: Yes locking your computer after x minutes is the solution.

Comment: But my connection stops after locking...

Comment: That is abnormal are we talking about wireless or wired connection?

Comment: I have tested with the wireless connection i havent tested the wired too...Can be this the problem?

Comment: What problem.  You being disconnected from the internet when your computer is locked is a different problem the stated question.

Comment: Ok i thought depended on it thanks for the explanation!
What i have to do?